# Method Chaining in Pandas: str.replace not working

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to read in an excel file, and using method chaining, convert the column names into lower case and replace any white space into _.  The following code runs fine

```
def supp_read(number):
    filename = f"supplemental-table{number}.xlsx"
    df = (pd.read_excel(filename,skiprows=5)
            .rename(columns = str.lower))
    return df
```

But the code below does not

```
def supp_read(number):
    filename = f"supplemental-table{number}.xlsx"
    df = (pd.read_excel(filename,skiprows=5)
            .rename(columns = str.lower)
            .rename(columns = str.replace(old=" ",new="_")))
    return df
```

After adding the `str.replace` line I get the following error: `No value for argument 'self' in unbound method call`. Can someone shed some light on what I can do to fix this error and why the above does not work?

In addition, when I use `str.lower()` I get the same error. Why does `str.lower` work but not `str.lower()`?

Comment: because `str.lower()` is calling the unbound method, and it's complaining it lacks it's self argument, which it does. When you pass `str.lower`, you are *passing the unbound method object itself*, which will then get called with a string, which it takes as it's self argument. You must pass a function, not the result of calling it, in this case, you want to partially apply the function, quick and dirty, pass `lambda s: s.replace(" ", "_")` instead of `str.replace(old=" ",new="_")`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga thank you that's exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Take a look at my answer @Gisela, see if it answers your Q

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a different syntax which I frequently use:

```
def supp_read(number):
    filename = f"supplemental-table{number}.xlsx"
    df = pd.read_excel(filename,skiprows=5)
    df.columns = df.columns.str.lower().replace(" ", "_")
    return df
```

Comment: Thank you, this also helped!